# How to transform file data in binary data in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multipartform-data, binaryfiles

I implement a file upload where the file is passed to the backend together with some data. File and data must be encoded as form data.

I have the upload implemented in two ways:

1. The formdata cotains the file as binary string
2. The formdata contains the file as normal string (link to the file)

The first option works for me and the file is uploaded successfully, while in the second case an error message appears:

> "The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the
>   form."

**1. File Upload with audio file as binary  string( Working )**

```
Form Data
audio: (binary)
title: Some Title
content: Some content
```

**1. The function and form that creates the form data with the audio file as binary ( Working )**

```
export class CreateStory extends Component {
  state = {
    title: "",
    content:"",
    audio:""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };


// Use Ref to clear  uncontrolled file field 
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
  }

 onChange = (e) => {
        if(e.target.name === 'audio') {
            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
            }, () => console.log(this.state.audio))

        } else {

            this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.value
            }, () => console.log(this.state))
        }
    }

onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let { title, content, audio} = this.state;
  let formDataStory = new FormData(); // create form formData
  formDataStory.append('audio', audio); // add audio to formData
  formDataStory.append('title', title); // add title to formData
  formDataStory.append('content', content); // add content to formData
  console.log (this.formDataStory);
  this.props.addStory(formDataStory) // call addStory function with formDataStory as Input to create new Story
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          title: "", // clear title field after submission
          content:"", // clear content field after submission
        });
        this.inputRef.current.value = ''; // clear file field after submission 
      }) 
};

  render() {
    const {title, content, audio} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="card card-body mt-4 mb-4">
        <h2>Add Story</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="title"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={title}
            />
             </div>
           <div className="form-group">
            <label>Content</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="text"
              name="content"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              value={content}
            />
          </div>

           <div className="form-group">
            <label>Audio</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="audio"
              onChange={this.onChange}
              ref={this.inputRef} // refer to ref

            />
          </div>

         <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect(
  null,
  { addStory }
)(CreateStory);
```

**2.File Upload with audio file as link ( Not Working )**

```
Form Data
audio: C:\Users\Some Link
title: Some Title
content: Some content
```

***2.The function and form that creates the form data with the audio file as link( Not Working )***

```
export class EditStory extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getStory = this.getStory.bind(this);
    this.updateStory = this.updateStory.bind(this);
    this.onChangeTitle = this.onChangeTitle.bind(this);
    this.onChangeContent=this.onChangeContent.bind(this);
    this.onChangeAudio=this.onChangeAudio.bind(this);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();


this.state = {
    story: {
        id: null,
        title: "",
        content: "",
        audio: ""
      }

    };
}


    componentDidMount() {
    this.getStory(this.props.match.params.id);
  }






  onChangeTitle(e) {
    const title = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      story: {
        ...prevState.title,
        title: title
      }
    }), () => console.log(this.state));
  }


  onChangeContent(e) {
    const content = e.target.value;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      story: {
        ...prevState.story,
        content: content
      }
    }), () => console.log(this.state));

  }


  onChangeAudio(e) {
const audio = e.target.name;

this.setState({
                [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
            }, () => console.log(this.state.audio))

        } 


 getStory(id) {
    this.props.getSingleStory(id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          story: response.data
        });

      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }



 updateStory() {


    let id = this.state.story.id;
    let title = this.state.story.title;
    let content = this.state.story.content;
    let audio = this.state.story.audio;
    let UpdatedData = new FormData();
    UpdatedData.append('id', id); 
    UpdatedData.append('audio', audio); // add audio to formData
    UpdatedData.append('title', title); // add title to formData
    UpdatedData.append('content', content);
    console.log (id);
    console.log (UpdatedData);
    this.props.editStory(
      id, 
      UpdatedData
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }





  static propTypes = {
      getSingleStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      editStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };


  render() {
    const {story} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Edit {story.title}</h1>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" defaultValue={story.title} onChange={this.onChangeTitle} className="form-control" />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Content</label>
            <textarea name="content" rows="5" defaultValue={story.content} onChange={this.onChangeContent} className="form-control" />
          </div>

     <div className="form-group">
         <label>Audio</label>
            <input
              className="form-control"
              type="file"
              name="audio"
              onChange={this.onChangeAudio}
              ref={this.inputRef} // refer to ref

            />
          </div>

          <div className="btn-group">
            <button type="submit" onClick={this.updateStory} className="btn btn-dark">Update</button>
            <button type="button"  className="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
          </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I do not understand why in the second case the audio file is not encoded as binary string. How do I transform in  second case the audio file into a binary string and add them to my form data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a minimum reproducible example, and the question is 1.6 years old, but no answer, so...

1. this spread expression uses title instead of story, so it wipes the other variables

   ```
   story: {
       ...prevState.title,
   ```
2. this sets state.audio, ignoring the fetched value in state.story

   ```
   this.setState({
       [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
   ```

   but the encoded value is state.story.audio

   ```
   let audio = this.state.story.audio;
   ```